I need chart_kit starting tips
Could anybody kickstart me with the hot fresh extension chart_kit?
https://lab.civicrm.org/ufundo/chart_kit
It states

This extension provides additional Search Display types for Search Kit for making chart

But I can't find any new display type in search kit.
Do I have to implement charts in js/angular? Or where is the UI entrypoint?
@ufundu?

Once you install the extension you can create chart displays via point-n-click. What do you mean by self-implementation?

Sorry, just updated the question. Wanted to know where to start, in my installation is no menu entry and I can't find new possibilities in search kit displays…

Installation seems hicked up, uninstall and reinstall fixed the problem.

If you are on a recent enough version and if the Chart Kit is enabled, then you should see the option to 'Add'  a Chart in the lower left corner where you also can "Add" a Table etc

I suspect that isn't the answer you need but it is a necessary stepping stone towards one.

That ist exactly what I wanted to know. And I was correctly assuming there should be such an entry but I'm afraid this isn't working on 5.75.0. I'm gonna have a look on the logs/browser console. Thx

Uninstall, Reinstall helped!
